# Merged 2 model objects in python and provided datas not showing in one row (used data tables to list datas from db)

Tags: python, django

I have created two models and using formset combined both models in one page. but when am trying to list out the datas in list page(using data tables, this will list created datas from db), it  is showing one models in one row and another models in 2nd row. I want to display it on same row using one id.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):

   EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   Employeemail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True, validators=[validate_email])
   EmployeeLocation = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='')
   EmployeeQualification = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Qualif_CHOICES, default='')
   EmployeePhoneNumber = models.IntegerField()
   class Meta:
      db_table = "generic"

class Example(models.Model):

    Experience = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=YEARS_CHOICES, default='')
    Address = models.CharField("Address Line 1", max_length=100, default='')
    zip_code = models.CharField("ZIP/Postal code", max_length=6, default='')
    LastWorked = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Test"
```

Comment: the two models aren't related (no foreign key or one-to-one relationship). so how do you want to determine which `Adding` belongs to which `Sensiple`?

Comment: Suggest me a solution how to relate these two models. Am totally new to python. Also i have no idea about foreign key

Comment: Read the documentation. Relationships are described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#relationships)